# TOR over VPN for home network

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, home-networking

I would like to use a VPN service that does not support a build in Tor over VPN option. So would there be a way to make this at home for the whole network?

Would something like this make sense?

Devices > VPN Router > Onion Router like Onion PI > ISP Router

In the end i would like to be possible to setup one of these Combinations:

User > VPN > Tor Nodes > Destination

or

User > VPN > Tor Nodes > VPN > Destination

Comment: There should be no problem with using Tor over VPN. Your config "User > VPN > Tor Nodes > Destination" is used by many, bit your other config is impossible (you can't dictate what the Tor nodes do).

Comment: Connect the VPN, then launch Tor.

Comment: Sorry to make this more clear: I don't want to use a VPN Client > and then the Tor Browser for example on every device. I would like to do this configuration on my Network hardware so that every device in my network has this type of connection :)

Comment: If the router has a VPN option, you can set it for everyone.

Comment: Sure i understand this thanks, but i would like to route every traffic also through Tor directly after the VPN, and i ask if this is some how possible when the VPN Provider does not support direct build in Tor over VPN support... So could i go from the VPN Router into a Onion Router/Box?

Comment: You would need to program your router, if it's Linux based. AFAIK using either VPN or TOR client is easy, but using both is hard and requires much knowledge (if at all possible).